# Ionic React: useHistory().push() not working when tapping FCM notification

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework

So I setup my push notification handler:

```
export function useInitializePushNotification() {

  const nav = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    PushNotifications.removeAllListeners().then(() => {
      ....

      // Method called when tapping on a notification
      PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed',
        (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
          let data = notification.notification.data;
          let url = `/application?applicationId=${data.applicationId}&app=${data.applicationName}&chatRoomId=${data.chatRoomId}&chatRoomName=${data.chatRoomName}&displayChat=true`.replace(/ /g, '-');
          nav.push(url);
        }
      );
    });

    return () => {
      PushNotifications.removeAllListeners();
    }
  }, [nav]);
}
```

From my `App.tsx`:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { setAuth } = useAuth(dispatch);
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);

  useInitializePushNotification();

  ....
```

`nav.push(url)` is changing my url, but routing does not work. The page does not change even after the navigation is changed. This happens only if I tap the notification from `FCM` on `background` mode, manual `nav.push()` is working if my app is in `foreground`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a lot, I finally found the solution. I use `Redux` to properly navigate it.

In my `pushNotificationActionPerformed` event:

```
    PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed',
      (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
        let data = notification.notification.data;
        let url = `/owner/support?id=${data.chatRoomId}&name=${data.chatRoomName}`;
        dispatch(setNeedNavigateTo(url));
      }
    );
```

I dispatch a url to be triggered in `App.tsx`.

This is my `App.tsx`:

```
  const needNavigateTo = useAppSelector((state) => state.support.needNavigateTo);

  const nav = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (nav && needNavigateTo) {
      nav.push(needNavigateTo); //this works
      setNeedNavigateTo(undefined); //set the url to undefined (resetting)
    }
  }, [nav, needNavigateTo]);
```

This solution is not ideal for those who do not use `Redux`, but this is the only way I found work. I am not sure if this solution work with `context`.